# Prolog delete: doesn't delete all elements that unify with Element

Tags: list, prolog

I'm having an issue with SWI-Prolog's `delete/3` predicate. 
The easiest way is just a quick example:

```
?- delete([(1,1),(1,2),(3,2)], (1,_), List).
List = [(1,2),(3,2)].
```

I would expect `(1,2)` to also be deleted, since `(1,_)` unifies with `(1,2)`. The SWIPL help says:

> Delete **all** members of `List1` that simultaneously unify with `Elem` and unify the result with `List2`.

Why is this and how can I delete everything that unifies with `(1,_)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

" Delete all members of List1 that **simultaneously** unify with Elem and unify the result with List2."

(1,X) first unifies with (1,1). therefore, X is unified with 1 and cannot be unified with 2 to delete (1,2).
so the problem is not that it does not delete **all** of the members; it's that it doesnt unify simultaneously with (1,2) and (1,1)
(try delete([(1,1),(1,2),(1,1),(3,2)],(1,_),List).

btw, according to the [swi-prolog manual](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=delete/3):

> > delete(?List1, ?Elem, ?List2)
> >         Is true when Lis1, with all occurences of Elem deleted results in List2.

also, delete/3 is deprecated:

> There are too many ways in which one might want to delete elements from a list to justify the name. 
>   Think of matching (= vs. ==), delete first/all, be deterministic or not.

So the easiest way is to write your own predicate. Something like:

```
my_delete(Pattern,[Pattern|T],TD):-
   my_delete(Pattern,T,TD).
my_delete(Pattern,[H|T],[H|TD]):-
   my_delete(Pattern,T,TD).
```

perhaps?

check [exclude/3, include/3, partition/4](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.2%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/apply.html%27%29%29)

Comment: All clauses of `my_delete/3` are recursive, that's too much:)

Answer (score 2):

Use [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`texclude/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963476/4609915) in combination with the 
[reified term equality predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13664870/4609915)
[`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915)!

First, we try using `(=)/3` directly...

```
?- texclude(=((1,V)), [(1,1),(1,2),(3,2)], KVs).
KVs = [      (1,2),(3,2)],     V=1            ;
KVs = [(1,1),      (3,2)],               V=2  ;
KVs = [(1,1),(1,2),(3,2)], dif(V,1), dif(V,2).
```

**Not quite!** For our next tries we are going to use [lambda expressions](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord).

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).
```

Let's query---once with [`texclude/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963476/4609915), once with [`tinclude/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963476/4609915), and once with [`tpartition/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915):

```
?- texclude(  \ (K,_)^(K=1), [(1,1),(1,2),(3,2)], Fs).
Fs = [(3,2)].                                     % succeeds deterministically

?- tinclude(  \ (K,_)^(K=1), [(1,1),(1,2),(3,2)], Ts).
Ts = [(1,1),(1,2)].                               % succeeds deterministically

?- tpartition(\ (K,_)^(K=1), [(1,1),(1,2),(3,2)], Ts,Fs).
Ts = [(1,1),(1,2)], Fs = [(3,2)].                 % succeeds deterministically
```

**Alright!** Do we get the same solutions if the list items are bound *after* the `texclude/3` call?

```
?- texclude(\ (K,_)^(K=1), [A,B,C], Fs), A = (1,1), B = (1,2), C = (3,2).
A = (1,1), B = (1,2), C = (3,2), Fs = [(3,2)] ;   % succeeds with choice point
false.
```

**Yes!** At last, consider the following quite general query:

```
?- texclude(\ (K,_)^(K=1), [A,B], Fs).
Fs = [   ], A = (  1,_A1), B = (  1,_B1)                         ;
Fs = [  B], A = (  1,_A1), B = (_B0,_B1),             dif(_B0,1) ;
Fs = [A  ], A = (_A0,_A1), B = (  1,_B1), dif(_A0,1)             ;
Fs = [A,B], A = (_A0,_A1), B = (_B0,_B1), dif(_A0,1), dif(_B0,1).
```

---

Note that above goals restrict **all** list items to have the form `(_,_)`. Thus the following query fails:

```
?- texclude(\ (K,_)^(K=1), [x,_], _).
false.
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer tries to generalize the idea presented in [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31087774/4609915).

Let's define a reified variant of `subsumes_term/2`:

```
list_nonvardisj([A],C) :- 
   !, 
   C = nonvar(A).
list_nonvardisj([A|As],(nonvar(A);C)) :-
   list_nonvardisj(As,C).

subsumes_term_t(General,Specific,Truth) :-
   subsumes_term(General,Specific),
   !,
   term_variables(General,G_vars),
   free4evrs(G_vars),
   Truth = true.
subsumes_term_t(General,Specific,Truth) :-
   Specific \= General,
   !,
   Truth = false.
subsumes_term_t(General,Specific,Truth) :-
   term_variables(Specific,S_vars),
   (  S_vars = [V]
   -> freeze(V,subsumes_term_t(General,Specific,Truth))
   ;  S_vars = [_|_]
   -> list_nonvardisj(S_vars,S_wakeup),
      when(S_wakeup,subsumes_term_t(General,Specific,Truth))
   ;  throw(error(instantiation_error, subsumes_term_t/3))
   ),
   (  Truth = true
   ;  Truth = false
   ).
```

The above definition of the reified predicate `subsumes_term_t/3` uses `free4evrs/1` to ensure that the "generic" term passed to `subsumes_term/2` is not instantiated any further.

For SICStus Prolog, we can define it as follows:

```
:- module(free4evr,[free4evr/1,free4evrs/1]).

:- use_module(library(atts)).

:- attribute nvrb/0.                       % nvrb ... NeVeR Bound

verify_attributes(V,_,Goals) :-
   get_atts(V,nvrb), 
   !,
   Goals = [throw(error(uninstantiation_error(V),free4evr/1))].
verify_attributes(_,_,[]).

attribute_goal(V,free4evr(V)) :-
   get_atts(V,nvrb).

free4evr(V) :-
   nonvar(V),
   !,
   throw(error(uninstantiation_error(V),free4evr/1)).
free4evr(V) :-
   (  get_atts(V,nvrb)
   -> true
   ;  put_atts(Fresh,nvrb),
      V = Fresh
   ).

free4evrs([]).
free4evrs([V|Vs]) :-
   free4evr(V),
   free4evrs(Vs).
```

Let's put `subsumes_term_t/3` to use!

```
?- texclude(subsumes_term_t(1-X), [A,B,C], Fs), A = 1-1, B = 1-2, C = 3-2.
A = 1-1, B = 1-2, C = 3-2, Fs = [C], free4evr(X) ? ;   % succeeds with choice-point
no

?- texclude(subsumes_term_t(1-X), [x,1-Y,2-3], Fs).
Fs = [x,2-3], free4evr(X) ? ;
no
```

What happens if we instantiate variable `X` in above query sometime after the call to `texclude/3`?

```
?- texclude(subsumes_term_t(1-X), [x,1-Y,2-3], Fs), X=something.
! error(uninstantiation_error(something),free4evr/1)
```